# removeprefix for string object is not an attribute

Tags: python, methods

I'm trying to test out all the methods for a string in order to understand and learn them, and I tried doing the following `removeprefix()` method, but it was not allowing me to do so. Is there some library problem I am having?

```
begone = 'begone'

newbegone = begone.removeprefix('be')
print(newbegone)
#print("Removing Prefix 'be':", begone.removeprefix('be'), ', new word')
#print("Removing Prefix 'gone':", begone.removeprefix('gone'), ', original word')
```

Comment: [That method was added in Python 3.9.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/) You're using an earlier version.

Comment: By the way, the specfic error is--- Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'

Answer (score 3):

`removeprefix` and `removesuffix` were added in Python 3.9. You're using an earlier version.

See [PEP-616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/).

To remove the prefix `'be'` from `begone` in prior versions, you can use a slice:

```
newbegone = begone[2:]
```

where 2 is the length of the prefix you are removing.

Comment: Ah i see, im using version 3.8.8 and not 3.9. Thank you.